# Updating multiple sub-documents via Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say for example, we're using the following schema to define a comments tree;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("id_here"),
    "parentComment" : "This is my opinion",
    "isHidden" : false,
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "comment" : "I disagree with your opinion",
            "isHidden" : false
        }, 
        {
            "comment" : "Test Post",
            "isHidden" : false
        }, 
        ....
}
```

So, if we were to update the parent comment to set the isHidden flag to true for banned phrases, we'd do so like this;

```
        var userComments = require('mongoose').model("UserComments");
        for (let i = 0; i < bannedPhrases.length; i++) {
            var conditions = { parentComment: bannedPhrases[i] }
                , update = { isHidden: true}
                , options = { multi: true };

            userComments.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
        }
```

Now, consider the subdocument "comments" (threaded comments, multiple entries) - how would we be able to go about updating these?

Comment: How do you query back the result?

Comment: How do you mean, as in query back the child comments subdocument? I just traverse through the tree in foreach loops to output everything. Getting the output is no issue - it's altering the multiple subdocuments that's causing the headache.

Comment: I can help you with for updating - pymongo, do you mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I can think of is to update the nested document one by one.

Assume we've got hold of the banned phrases, which is an array of strings:

```
var bannedPhrases = ["censorship", "evil"]; // and more ...
```

Then we perform a query to find all `UserComments` which has `comments` that contain any of the `bannedPhrases`.

```
UserComments.find({"comments.comment": {$in: bannedPhrases }});
```

By using promises, we can perform update asynchronously together:

```
UserComments.find({"comments.comment": {$in: bannedPhrases }}, {"comments.comment": 1})
  .then(function(results){
    return results.map(function(userComment){

       userComment.comments.forEach(function(commentContainer){
         // Check if this comment contains banned phrases
         if(bannedPhrases.indexOf(commentContainer.comment) >= 0) {
           commentContainer.isHidden = true;
         }
       });

       return userComment.save();
    });
  }).then(function(promises){
     // This step may vary depending on which promise library you are using
     return Promise.all(promises); 
  });
```

If you use [Bluebird JS](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) is Mongoose's promise library, the code could be simplified:

```
UserComments.find({"comments.comment": {$in: bannedPhrases}}, {"comments.comment": 1})
    .exec()
    .map(function (userComment) {

        userComment.comments.forEach(function (commentContainer) {
            // Check if this comment contains banned phrases
            if (bannedPhrases.indexOf(commentContainer.comment) >= 0) {
                commentContainer.isHidden = true;
            }
        });

        return userComment.save();
    }).then(function () {
    // Done saving
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This link should help:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

What you can do is:

`ParentComment.findById(parentCommendId, {'comments.$[].isHidden': true})`

In english, this is saying, find the comment with id `parentCommendId` and set **all** of its child comments' isHidden fields to true.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

To update all the subdocuments,

```
db.coll.update({}, {$set: {“a.$[].b”: 2}})
Input: {a: [{b: 0}, {b: 1}]}
Output: {a: [{b: 2}, {b: 2}]}
```

To update only the matching subdocuments,

```
db.coll.update({"a.b":0}, {$set: {“a.$[i].b”: 2}}, {arrayFilters: [{“i.b”: 0}]})
Input: {a: [{b: 0}, {b: 1}]}
Output: {a: [{b: 2}, {b: 1}]}
```

For more insights on updating subdocuments, Please refer to this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) ticket.