# How to update specific field in mongoDB given conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following mongdoDB structure, how can i update the field `isAvailable` to `false` given that the `shopName` is `"jamrt"` and `slug` is `"67626dae-1537-40d8-837d-483e5759ada0"`. This is my query but it does not work: `Shop.find({ shopName: shopName}).update({products: {$elemMatch: {slug: slug}}}, { $set: { isAvailable: req.body.isAvailable} }` Thanks!

```
"shopName": "jmart",
"products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Clean and Clear Deep Clean Cleanser 100g",
        "slug": "8d1c895c-6911-4fc8-a34c-89c6948233d7",
        "price": 4.5,
        "discount_price": 0,
        "category": "Health and Beauty",
        "sale": false,
        "subcategory": "personal care",
        "color": "black",
        "article": "Clean and Clear",
        "quantity": 9,
        "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/swifty-products.appspot.com/o/Jmart%2FBeauty%2FClean%20and%20Clear%20Deep%20Clean%20Cleanser%20100g.jpg?alt=media",
        "vendor": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Clean and Clear"
        },
        "ratings": {
            "star_ratings": 0,
            "votes": 0
        },
        "isAvailable": true
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Colgate Total Pro Breath Health",
        "slug": "67626dae-1537-40d8-837d-483e5759ada0",
        "price": 4.5,
        "discount_price": 0,
        "category": "Health and Beauty",
        "sale": false,
        "subcategory": "personal care",
        "color": "black",
        "article": "Colgate",
        "quantity": 9,
        "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/swifty-products.appspot.com/o/Jmart%2FBeauty%2FColgate%20Total%20Pro%20Breath%20Health.jpg?alt=media",
        "vendor": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Colgate"
        },
        "ratings": {
            "star_ratings": 0,
            "votes": 0
        },
        "isAvailable": true
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are trying to update only the matching sub documents.

The $elemMatch operator while using in projection updates only the first matching sub document.
The $elemMatch operator while using in find updates all the fields of the matching document.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62947196/2579739) might help you.

With your case, the solution might be the below in mongodb query:

```
db.Shop.update({"shopName":"jmart","products.slug":"67626dae-1537-40d8-837d-483e5759ada0"}, {$set: {“products.$[i].isAvailable”: false}}, {arrayFilters: [{“i.slug”: "67626dae-1537-40d8-837d-483e5759ada0"}]})
```